# OneLogin - OpenID Connect - Unable to use custom URL scheme? Ionic/Cordova

Tags: openid, onelogin

How can I send the OpenID redirect to a custom url endpoint with OneLogin?  I'm trying to embed our OneLogin in our mobile apps and it's not letting me redirect to a custom url prefix. like `myapp://token`.  This is the way to use chrome tabs or the inappbrowser in a cordova app.  It seems to work for other OpenID ID providers.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the supported protocol is HTTPS. (or http://localhost permitted for development purposes).

You will need to add your callback url to the list of approved Redirect URIs for your OneLogin OIDC app via the Admin portal.

See step 5 of https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/connect-to-onelogin).

Comment: So there is no way to use Onelogin OpenID connect in a Hybrid app?

Answer (score 0):

This capability is currently in beta at OneLogin and will be GA within a few weeks.

Comment: Is that accessible to current customers for beta?  If so, who do I talk to or contact?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. I missed this one. The ability to use Custom URL Schemes as the redirect_uri was released as GA late in October 2018 and is available on all accounts.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try